# Cannot figure out how to incorporate backtracking into my psuedo-recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

This is for a sudoku-solver and each square has this method. My idea is that if one instance of this method goes through the loop without finding any valid values, it will return to the previous method that called it and continue the loop - trying the next value from the for-loop. I was hoping that this would suffice for backtracking, but all my test fail and I am completely clueless as to how I'm going to solve this one. /end noob-lament

```
public boolean recursive() {

    for(int i = 1; i <= boardSize; i++) {

        if(!validValue(i)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            setValue(i);

            if(getNext() == null) // This signifies that I am at the end of the list
                return true;
            else 
                getNext().recursive(); // same method in the next sudoku square
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This code isn't really sufficient to see what's going on.  What's the structure of the algorithm and what do `validValue`, `setValue`, `getNext`, and `recursive` do?  Though I can't say with confidence what's wrong, my guess is that you are not undoing changes during backtracking.  When a search fails to find a solution, it should reset any persistent state that it has changed before backtracking.

Comment: Sorry, I made a bad assumption thinking that the method names were self-explanatory. validValue(i) checks the if i is found in the box/row/column that pertains to the square. setValue() is a setter to the value in each square. getNext() returns the next square on the sudoku board. I'm sorry for not seeing this, but why do I have to reset the value if the method setValue() will just overwrite any wrong value?

Comment: Then it's probably not relevant for your case.  In some search algorithms, a recursive instance can overwrite a guess made by an earlier step.  Since each recursive instance modifies a separate piece of data in your algorithm, undoing doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Two correctness issues here:

1. You should check if the result from the recursive invokation was `true` - and if it is, you should stop the recursion - you have found a solution, don't override it!
2. You should bubble up the return value of the recursion, specifically - if `getNext().recursive();` yields `true` - you should bubble this `true` up [and as said in (1) - stop the recursion, you have a solution!]

Comment: Thank you for your invaluable input. I have edited the code above to reflect your input, but being the noob that I am I feel that I am stabbing this one in the blind. I believe I understand how recursive functions work, but it's the implementing part that seems to give me troubles. Does my edit above reflect your advice, or am I completely off?

Comment: @jollyroger: It solves the problems I addressed - I have no idea if it will now be correct. Also: I am reverting the code back to the original, because others might learn from it as well! If the code is still failing, you should post a new question that describes how and why the code fails.

Answer (score 1):

OK - so since a fellow peer of mine helped me out with this one and managed to get me to understand what was missing, I thought I'd like to share it here in case anyone would be interested to know what was missing.

After the loop is done, the method needs to reset its value. If not the old values that were previously tested before the backtrack would remain after the backtrack. That would mean that when the isValid() method would check the column, row and box that the given square belongs to, the isValid() method would find a lot of values set previously.

All that was needed was one line before 'return false;'

```
//(end of for-loop)  
setValue(0);  
return false;  
//(method ends)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling getNext() twice. If it doesn't return null in your if statement, you call it again. Are you sure you want to do that?